# Django fixtures for permissions

Tags: django, fixtures

I'm creating fixtures for permissions in Django. I'm able to get them loaded the way it's needed. However, my question is..say I want to load a fixture for the table `auth_group_permissions`, I need to specify a `group_id` and a `permission_id`, unfortunately fixtures aren't the best way to handle this. Is there an easier way to do this programmatically? So that I can get the `id` for particular values and have them filled in? How is this normally done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper solution is to create the permissions in the same manner the framework itself does.

You should connect to the built-in [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-syncdb) signal either in the module `management.py` or `management/__init__.py` and create the permissions there. The documentation does say that any work performed in response to the `post_migrate` signal should not perform any database schema alterations, but you should also note that the framework itself creates the permissions in response to this signal.

So I'd suggest that you take a look at the [management module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py#L126) of the `django.contrib.auth` application to see how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 20):

As of at least Django >=1.7, it is now possible to store permissions in fixtures due to the introduction of "natural keys" as a serialization option.

You can read more about natural keys in the [Django serialization documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys)

The documentation explicitly mentions the use case for natural keys being when..

> ...objects are automatically created by Django during the database synchronization process, the primary key of a given relationship isn’t easy to predict; it will depend on how and when migrate was executed. This is true for all models which automatically generate objects, notably including Permission, Group, and User.

So for your specific question, regarding `auth_group_permissions`, you would dump your fixture using the following syntax:

`python manage.py dumpdata auth --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e auth.Permission`

The auth_permissions table must be explicitly excluded with the `-e` flag as that table is populated by the `migrate` command and will already have data prior to loading fixtures.

This fixture would then be loaded in the same way as any other fixtures

Comment: Where should i put this file? The documentation says to put it inside of app_name/fixtures/... But Permissions is a baked in app. Whats the best practice here?

Comment: I found answer myself. Django looks for fixture files inside `settings.FIXTURE_DIRS` and into `*appnames*/fixtures`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @jonpa's comment, if you are using multitenant app and you want to directly save the fixtures to a file you can do:

`python manage.py tenant_command dumpdata --schema=<schema_name> --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e auth.Permission --indent 4 > /path/to/fixtures/fixtures.json`