# How to real named auth_group_permissions in Django?

Tags: python, django, fixtures

I want to create fixtures for auth_group_permissions table, but how named it model?
'auth.group.permissions' is not right.

```
[
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {"name": "manager"}
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {"name": "executive"}
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {"name": "ordinar"}
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group.permissions",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
                    "group_id": 1,
                    "permission_id": 7
                    }
    }

]
```

Comment: Refer to this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334799/django-fixtures-for-permissions

Comment: "but how named it model", I don't need signals, raw sql or else, just one string, ok?

Comment: try Permissions or Group_Permissions

Comment: Try this:

`{
    "model": "auth.group",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "manager",
        "permissions" : [7]
    }
}`

or 

"permissions" : [{"pk": 7}]

Class group has many-to-many field permissions, so you should use it.

Comment: @DenisNikanorov Many thx, namesake. All works fine )

Comment: @Denis but accepted answer isn't mine(

Comment: @DenisNikanorov Sry ... but you don't post your own answer, if you want you can post and I upvote. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define them in the group as related field

```
   "model": "auth.group",
        "fields": {
            "name": "foo",
            "permissions": [
                ...
            ]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no model named group.permissions in auth app. But class `Group` has many-to-many field permissions, so you should use it for your purpose.

Try this fixture:

```
{
    "model": "auth.group",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "manager",
        "permissions" : [7]
    }
}
```